# Alerting Library Users to an Inconsistent State

Tags: c#, .net

In a managed wrapper over a native library, I have to accomplish certain operations which to the user of the high level objects should be considered atomic and consistent. However, the underlying operations in native code are atomic and consistent individually, but not as a whole.

```
// Simplistic look at the AddRange operation
void AddRange(IEnumerable<ChildType> range)
{
    foreach (var value in range)
    {
        this.NativeAdd(value);
    }
}

// Simplistic look at the Delete operation
void Delete(ParentType value)
{
    foreach (var child in value.Children)
    {
        this.NativeDelete(child);
    }

    this.NativeDelete(value);
}
```

All of the Native operations fail with a common exception type if the Native code relates there has been an error:

```
void NativeDelete(ChildType child)
{
    StatusCode status = StatusCode.NoError;
    NativeMethods.DeleteChild(this.id, child.Id, out status);

    if (status != StatusCode.NoError)
    {
        throw new LibraryException(this, child, status);
    }
}
```

In the high-level AddRange and Delete routines I run into the situation where some of either the native Add or Delete calls have completed, but an error occurs in one of them and the rest do not complete.

**UPDATE:** The actual file on disk, to a user, will not look any different if they added 7 items and it failed on the 7th item, or if they added 6 items successfully. The only time the error is recorded is during runtime. Therefore, if the user is not made aware of the possibility of an inconsistent state, they may not be able to decide if the underlying file is valid.

Should I:

1. Let the LibraryException through and provide documentation to the user that the ParentType or ChildType object may be in an inconsistent state
2. Wrap the LibraryException in an InconsistentStateException containing information about which objects may be in an inconsistent state
3. Catch the LibraryException and attempt to "hand" rollback the changes made, before rethrowing the exception for the user (not a fan of this)
4. Something else?

Comment: What the caller should do upon encountering that state?

Comment: @peterchen: I've updated the question to include what a failed file looks like to a user (preview: it looks normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your update correctly, all the caller can do is pass the information on to the end user, who has to decide whether to accept the state, or to roll back.

In that case, (2): provide all information so the caller can pass the information to the user, or a log file, or some statistics without a lot of work.

(1) would be ok if there is no informational difference to (2), e.g. knowing which item failed is irrelevant.

(3) is pointless if you can't expect fix it most of the time, and dangerous if there is the slightest chance you make it worse.

Depending on the file size you might be able to make the change quasi-atomic by working on a copy. At least, the user would probably expect an easy way to roll back to the last save.

Comment: I'd considered the copy scheme, however, the average file size tends to be in the 100MiB range. I don't think I have any good choice to this problem.

Comment: I guessed they'd be to big. 
Another idea, but it's expensive: as "working file format", use one where change/rollback IS atomic, and provide conversion to the original file format. This could be a structured file format or small separate files.

Answer (score 2):

3 just isn't possible without a true two-phase commit support (i.e. a transaction manager).  Rolling back by hand is just going to lead you to more of an inconsistent state if an error occurs there.

I think 2 is redundant.  If you call a method on the parent type (which is where these methods exposed) and you have an exception that occurs when you throw that exception, the assumption is that the state on the object is corrupted (with the exception of a few exceptions).  Generally, when that occurs, you can't do much with the object except throw it away and use a new one with a consistent state.

That leaves 1, to document it.  While you might give a lot of structured information in 2, if the object is in an inconsistent state, you *really* don't want to try and fix that state, as you run a greater risk of screwing it up more.

Comment: To you point on #2, the user won't be able to tell if they go and look at the file if 6 of 7 succeeded and 1 failed, or 6 of 6 succeeded. Only during the execution of the program will they know it is trashed. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Not much.  Since you are seeking to enforce ACID here, if the exception goes through, and you can't roll back, you have to assume the entire batch is inconsistent.  You could add some details, but doing that with the hope that the user will recover (in code) is a bad idea.

Comment: More I'm looking to let them know that in certain instances they should not trust the consistency of the file. Not every error would cause this, but in AddRange/Delete it would. Without knowing the program died, they can't tell a good from a bad file.

Answer (score 1):

I like your second option -

This would provide a much more meaningful exception, which you'd control.  There's no reason to force your end users to understand some strange status codes, etc.  At least this way, it'll be obvious what happened and why.